# UIViewController dealloc never called with Cordova

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I have a UIViewController in Which I have added a CDVViewController.
This is my Code:

MyController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CDVViewController* cordovaViewController;
```

MyController.m

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.cordovaViewController = [[CDVViewController alloc]init];
    self.cordovaViewController.startPage = [[WL sharedInstance]mainHtmlFilePath];
    [self addChildViewController:self.cordovaViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.cordovaViewController.view];
}
```

When I press the button for close this Controller this method is invoked:

```
-(void)closeApp
{
    [self.cordovaViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.cordovaViewController.view removeFromSuperview];            
    [self.cordovaViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    self.cordovaViewController = nil;
}
```

The dealloc method is never called

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Module deallocated!");
}
```

If i do not add the cordova controller to my viewcontroller and call the closeApp method, the dealloc is called.

How can i solve my situation?

Thank you so much

Comment: Is your project using ARC?

Comment: No my project is not using ARC

Comment: Since you aren't using ARC you need to autorelease CDVViewController: [[[CDVViewController alloc] init] autorelease]

Comment: Sorry I was sleeping...my project is using ARC ... sorry for the mistake